# Nested Insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested

I'm trying to write a nested insert into query and I want to insert the values, which are inserted in "Table1", in a new table "Table3".

"Table3" has exactly the same columns as "Table1", but without the second insert into value into "Table2".

"Table1" already contains old data, but only the new data inserted in "Table1" should be inserted in "Table3".

```
-- insert new rows in History

INSERT INTO "table1"
  ([icao24], [callsign])
SELECT
  CurInserts.icao24
 ,CurInserts.[callsign]
FROM
(
-- INSERT new rows FROM temptable IN currenttable
    INSERT INTO "table2"
      ([icao24], [callsign])
    OUTPUT
       inserted.[icao24]
      ,inserted.[callsign]
    SELECT
       T.[icao24]
      ,T.[callsign]
    FROM @TempTable T
    LEFT JOIN "table2" Cur
      ON T.[icao24] = Cur.[icao24]
    WHERE Cur.[icao24] IS NULL
) CurInserts;
```

Comment: I got a hunch that this is more often solved via an `after insert` trigger.  Actually the first time I come accross a question that does it like this.

Comment: @Stu That's not actually true, a `INSERT...OUTPUT` can go into a `SELECT` but then the results must go straight into another `INSERT` with no further processing, you cannot `INSERT` a third time. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#inserting-data-returned-from-an-output-clause-into-a-table

Comment: Side point: `LEFT JOIN...IS NULL` is generally less efficient than `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

You could first insert the inserted into another table variable or a temporary table.

Then insert into the 2 other tables from the table variable.

**Demonstration**

> ```
> declare @tmp table (icao24 int, callsign int);
> declare @ins table (icao24 int, callsign int);
> insert into @tmp (icao24, callsign) values (1,10),(2,20),(3,30);
>
> insert into @ins (icao24, callsign)
> select icao24, callsign
> from
> (
>   insert into table1 (icao24, callsign)
>   output inserted.icao24, inserted.callsign
>   select tmp.icao24, tmp.callsign
>   from @tmp tmp
>   left join table1 t on t.icao24 = tmp.icao24
>   where t.icao24 is null
> ) q;
>
> insert into table2 (icao24, callsign)
> select icao24, callsign 
> from @ins;
>
> insert into table3 (icao24, callsign)
> select icao24, callsign 
> from @ins;
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1;
> select * from table2;
> select * from table3;
> ```
>
> ```
> icao24 | callsign
> -----: | -------:
>      1 |       10
>      2 |       20
>      3 |       30
>
> icao24 | callsign
> -----: | -------:
>      1 |       10
>      2 |       20
>      3 |       30
>
> icao24 | callsign
> -----: | -------:
>      2 |       20
>      3 |       30
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2da3518c26f07ef6f418c7d78d487e82)*